# Unhide rows one by one

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA to unhide rows one by one in certain order. So by clicking button rows are getting unhidden in certain order one by one. The problem with current solution is that it is too long and complex. I would like to make code more shorter and effective. Ranges are in 5 row increments starting from 174 -1 and reducing, so I think there should be some better solution for making some mathematics function doing this procedure.

Unhide rows:

```
Sub UnhideJobs()
Static counter As Byte

    counter = (counter + 1) Mod 26

    Select Case counter
                Case 1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("169:173").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                Case 2
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("164:168").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                Case 3
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("159:163").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                Case 4
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("154:158").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Case 5
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("149:153").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Case 6
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("144:148").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Case 7
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("139:143").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Case 8
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("134:138").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Case 9
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("129:133").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Case 10
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("124:128").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Case 11
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("119:123").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Case 12
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("114:118").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Case 13
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("109:113").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Case 14
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("104:108").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Case 15
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("99:103").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Case 16
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("94:98").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Case 17
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("89:93").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Case 18
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("84:88").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Case 19
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("79:83").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Case 20
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("74:78").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Case 21
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("69:73").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Case 22
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("64:68").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Case 23
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("59:63").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Case 24
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("54:58").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Case 25
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("49:53").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Case 26
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("49:53").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Select
End Sub
```

Hide all:

```
Sub HideAllJobs()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
Rows("49:173").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You are not explicitly specifying which sheet the un-hiding is in. I'd prefix all those unhiding lines with Thisworkbook.Sheets("Filling form").     just in case some other part of your code is changing the active sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset your Counter to 0 in HideAllJobs and use a Public variable in place of the static line

```
Public counter As Integer

Sub HideAllJobs()
   'Static counter As Byte
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
   Rows("49:173").EntireRow.Hidden = True
   counter = 0
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub UnhideJobs()
    'Static counter As Byte
    counter = (counter + 1) Mod 26
    Select Case counter
      Case 1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("169:173").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 2
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("164:168").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 3
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("159:163").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 4
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("154:158").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 5
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("149:153").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 6
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("144:148").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 7
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("139:143").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 8
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("134:138").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 9
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("129:133").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 10
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("124:128").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 11
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("119:123").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 12
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("114:118").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 13
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("109:113").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 14
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("104:108").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 15
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("99:103").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 16
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("94:98").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 17
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("89:93").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 18
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("84:88").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 19
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("79:83").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 20
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("74:78").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 21
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("69:73").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 22
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("64:68").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 23
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("59:63").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 24
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("54:58").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 25
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("49:53").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Case 26
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
            Rows("49:53").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Select
End Sub
```

Addendum - New condensed UnHide Routine

```
Sub NewUnhideJobs()
    Dim RngTxt As String, RngAR() As String, ThisRng As String

    counter = (counter + 1) Mod 26
    counter = IIf(counter = 0, 1, counter)

    RngTxt = "169:173_164:168_159:163_154:158_149:153_144:148_139:143_134:138_129:133"
    RngTxt = RngTxt & "_124:128_119:123_114:118_109:113_104:108_99:103_94:98"
    RngTxt = RngTxt & "_89:93_84:88_79:83_74:78_69:73_64:68_59:63_54:58_49:53_49:53"

    RngAR = Split(RngTxt, "_")
    ThisRng = RngAR(counter - 1)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Rows(ThisRng).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You could also use a simpler method and reduce code further - your ranges are in 5 row increments starting from 174 -1 and reducing, so

```
ThisRng = "" & (174 - (counter * 5)) & ":" & (174 - (counter * 5) + 4)
```

would work and eliminate a few more lines

=====================================

As per comments

I had the following line wrong originally

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Rows(ThisRng).EntireRow.Hidden = False
```

Comment: Sort of but not quite. - modifying answer ... 2 mins

Comment: You could also massively reduce the size of that block of code by putting those ranges into a string or string array

Comment: Yes, apologies, I've edited since then - ThisRng should be in the line       "ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Rows(ThisRng).EntireRow.Hidden = False"     it wasn't earlier

Comment: @user7202022 You should only have about 30 lines of code now in 2 procedures. If you want to post that again as an edit to your question I'll see where the problem is.