# Unhide rows in logical order

Tags: excel, vba

I have code for Hiding and Unhiding rows in Excel sheet. With help of user1302114 ([Unhide rows one by one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54863128/)) code was shorten and now it is functioning much more quicker.

Current problem is:

1. Running twice `NewUnhideJobs` (position of second section)
2. Running once `HideAllJobs`
3. Running `NewUnhideJobs`

As the result we have position of third section and not first as it should be. So `NewUnhideJobs` does not start from 0 but continues to do previous procedure.

Removing of `Static counter As Byte` was tried but code does not work without it.

`counter = 0` was also tried in `HideAllJobs` without success.

Hiding rows:

```
Sub NewUnhideJobs()
Static counter As Byte
    Dim RngTxt As String, RngAR() As String, ThisRng As String

    counter = (counter + 1) Mod 26

    ThisRng = "" & (174 - (counter * 5)) & ":" & (174 - (counter * 5) + 4)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Rows(ThisRng).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Unhiding rows:

```
Sub HideAllJobs()
   Static counter As Byte
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
   Rows("49:173").EntireRow.Hidden = True
   counter = 0
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Posted also here: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1088860-excel-vba-unhiding-rows-logical-order.html#post5233153

Comment: Try to declare `Public counter As Long` **outside** of  all subs at the top of your module. And remove the `Static counter As Byte` in your subs. Otherwise `counter = 0` will not have any effect on the counter in `NewUnhideJobs`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ seems working now! Thank you master! I think you can add your comment as an answer!

Comment: done, you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must declare your counter as a global variable.

```
Public counter As Long 'public variable

Sub NewUnhideJobs()
    Dim RngTxt As String, RngAR() As String, ThisRng As String

    counter = (counter + 1) Mod 26

    ThisRng = "" & (174 - (counter * 5)) & ":" & (174 - (counter * 5) + 4)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Rows(ThisRng).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Sub HideAllJobs()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
   Rows("49:173").EntireRow.Hidden = True
   counter = 0
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Otherwise your `counter = 0` doesn't have any effect on the counter in `NewUnhideJobs` because you have declared 2 distinct `counter` variables, one for each procedure/sub.